# Storaging document in mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB as my DB in my node.js application. My clarification is

consider i have 2 collections as A, B.

B's document structure is

```
{
"key1":"value1",
"key2":[_id(1) from collection A,
        _id(2) from collection A,
        ,,,so on..
       ]
}
```

So when i retrieving collection B , i should have to retrieve the details of collection A also. So i have to loop here for(key2) and find the details from collection A which is tedious.

My question is whether its better to store along with details? like us below

```
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":[{
              "keyA":"valueA"
            },
            {
              "KeyA":"valueA"
            }
            ,,,so on..
           ]
    }
```

Now its just retrieve no for loop here. Also in the above case user can update the `"key2"` can remove , add from frontend. In this case its good to delete the document and create a new one with updated array?

Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have simple updating, deleting and retrieving, maybe you should think about table that connect A and B.

Let's say this collection name is AB

```
{
   keyAB: "keyAB"
   keyA: "valueA",
   keyB: "keyB"
}
```

In this case, you would add new document for every connection. Retrieving, deleting and updating is easy in this case as you just delete one document.

If you really don't want to have third collection then you could do

```
{
"key1":"value1",
"key2":{"keyA1": "valueA1",
        "keyA2": "valueA2",...
        }
}
```

In that case, for updating and retrieving values you would just get key2[keyA1] for getting value or delete key2[keyA1] for deleting.